# Search by select query(or alternative) using array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

```
get_srv_id = Service.find_all_by_objt_id(page_records.collect(&:objt_id))
```

From this request, I'm getting ID's that I need to check:

```
[5152, 3876]
```

The next step is to compare and select only those values where srv_id matches.

```
int_service_attributes.select {|element| element.srv_id == get_srv_id.each {|elem| elem.id} }
```

But this is now working as get_srv_idis an array.

int_service_attributes is used as a class method `has many`.

Ruby: 1.8.7

Rails: 2.3.4

Yes, I do know that the version are old like dinosaurs, but there is no availability to upgrade now.

Comment: Can you do something like `get_srv_id.include?(element.srv_id)` (within the select block)?

Comment: This sounds like something that should be done by using a join and `.where`.

Comment: @max I mentioned rails version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for solution  Sebastian Palma

The answer is:

```
int_service_attributes.select {|element| get_srv_id.include?(element.srv_id) }
```